# filling city dropdown based on multiselect states in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, multi-select

I am creating a form where user can select a country from a drop-down list, then based on selected country, all related states filled in a multi-select list-box. Now a user can select multiple states and based on selected states another multi-select list-box (assigned for cities) should be filled accordingly. How can achieve this?

[image]

Html:-

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged">/asp:DropDownList>

<asp:ListBox ID="ddlState" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" CssClass="form-control multiselectmulticolumnddl" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>

<asp:ListBox ID="ddlCity" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" CssClass="form-control multiselectmulticolumnddl"></asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: I used OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged" event of ddlState, but it works only when i change country dropdown.

Comment: you should share your backend code. Edit post and share your backend code pls.

Comment: i am still confused which event should be used for this..

Answer (score 0):

For ListBox you need to use the [SelectedIndexChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged.aspx).

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ddlState" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="form-control multiselectmulticolumnddl"></asp:ListBox>
```

And you also need to use Ajax for Partial posting.

Comment: I think you call the same event on both control.
you need to create different event for both controls

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you already have a list of the states. Since ur selectedindexchanged on ddlCountry fires.

```
protected void ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // Make a stateList where we store all stateIDs. 
    List<int> stateList = new List<int>();

    // Loop through all items and check if they are selected. If yes then we add them to our list of selected items.
    foreach (ListItem state in ddlState.Items)
    {
     if(state.selected){
     {
    //we add the ID of the state. 
     stateList.Add(state.ID)
     }
    }
 // get all city's assosiated with the states in the stateList
}
```

This will give you a list of the stateIDs. Use this list to fill in the city's.

Hope this is what u looking for.

Edit: make sure you give this listbox it's own index changed event

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ddlState" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" CssClass="form-control multiselectmulticolumnddl" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: i changed the main code. Is this what you looking for?